# Combining the output of Get-Childitem into the [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom(...)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to search for all assemblies with certain name in my hard drive and check its version at the same time. My question is how to redirect the output of the Get-Childitem into the LoadFrom(x).
The following command lists me all assemblies I am searching for:

```
Get-Childitem –Path C:\ -Include Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

and at the same time I want to see the assembly version using the following command:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\....\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll").GetName().Version
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ForEach-Object` loop, but I'd also suggest using `-Filter` over `-Include` for speed:

```
Get-Childitem -Path C:\ -Filter Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll -Recurse -ErrorAction Ignore |
    ForEach-Object {
        "Checking: $($PSItem.FullName)"
        [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($PSItem.FullName).GetName().Version
    }
```